# Checks for AC Mains Product Compliance

Tags: mains, compliance

First of, I apologize if this type of question has been answered before (I did have a search).

We are a small startup about to go through manufacturing stage of a product.
I would like to ensure that our design meets FCC & RCM compliance checks. I feel confident (from research) that the product will pass with MCU & Radio checks. We used reference designs that have been approved.

The only gray area is mains. In particular, whether this reference would trouble passing compliance checks:
[image: AC to DC Refence]
<sub>(source: [datasheetdir.com](http://circuits.datasheetdir.com/64/LNK302-circuits.jpg))</sub>

Is there someone would have pointers on product compliance with AC? (Regions; EU, AU, USA..)

Thanks

Comment: This subcircuit by itself is fine; it's straight out of the manufacturer's datasheet. However, any time you use a non-isolated power supply, your entire product will be subject to safety tests that make sure no one can come into contact with any electrical conductor, even after any single failure (so-called "double insulation").

Comment: Are there any buttons/displays/connectors (other than the mains plug) on the product, or does it entirely communicate through power-line and/or radio comms?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. 

Dave, the product will be installed by electricians - they will be exposed to the conductive parts during installation only.

After installation, only 1 button is accessible. The rest is via bluetooth (the product is ceiling mounted)